# How to pass a python list of URLs to a Django template and make them clickable?

Tags: python, django

I have a python list of urls which looks like this:

```
list = ['/abc/1', 
       '/abc/3',
       '/abc/5',
       ...
       ]
```

all these urls follow the url pattern 'abc/n/' which I have defined in urls.py.
now I want to pass this list to a django template in such a way that each element of this list becomes clickable and runs the function corresponding to their url pattern on clicking them.
I tried hardcoding the anchor tag to each element of this list. for example

```
for i in range (len(list)):    
    list[i] = "<a href = \'" + list[i] + "\'>click me</a>"
```

and then sending this list to template via `HttpResponse()` function via a context. But this displayed the list items in raw text format instead of links

Comment: how are you generating that list if I may ask?

Comment: 1) don't use `list` as a variable. 2) don't modify a list while looping over it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is happening here is that django is being safe and escaping your html. This is to prevent XSS vunerabilities. This is a vulnerability that happens when e.g. users can insert malicious HTML into your site.

Now, you could turn that off, but then you risk having the aforementioned security issues.

What you will want to do instead is generate the html in the template, not in your code (that's what templates are there for):

```
{% for link in links %}
<a href="{{ link }}">click me</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Now you just need to pass `links` in your template context!

Comment: Aren't inverted commas needed around `{{ link }}` in the href?

Comment: was gonna do myself but 2 characters isn't considered worthy by stackoverflow edit standards :')

Comment: TIL: Inverted commas mean Quotation marks, thank you.

Comment: afaict, inverted commas usually refers to ' though, not "

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a for loop format the links as html, just pass the list directly into your context then within your django template use:

```
{% for item in list %}
    <a href="{{ item }}">Link text</a>
{% endfor %}
```

If your links are not all going to be placed on the page consecutively, you can just use:

```
{{ list.index }}
```

with index being the index of the item you wish to access

Comment: In the manual index case, using a different variable/name for each link would be highly preferred

Comment: @Azsgy true but just working with what the op has given me. Might be the case that the number of links is unknown